# Angular duplicates track by

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-track-by

I have this plunk:

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/7X8VMG?p=preview
```

and when I filter by clicking **"Uncompleted"** I'm getting the duplicates error in repeater

```
 Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: node in nodes track by node.id, Duplicate key: 1441, Duplicate value: {"name":"1","id":1441,"created_at":...
```

But if you look to the code, **there is only one node with ID 1441**. I've tried to put there others track by options, but nothing worked.

//Update info:
Track by $index doesn't work because of nested structure

How to fix it?

Thanks a lot!

David

Comment: I debugged your code. You have used 'nodesFilter' to find out the resulted nodes. It is adding duplicate object with ID(1441) when you clicking **"Uncompleted"**.  Need to refine.

Comment: `ng-repeat="obj in collection track by $id(obj)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in **setFilterOptions** function that there was more status with same code and then it pushed more often the node to the result array.

fixed by

```
if($scope.current_visibility.since === null) {
    $scope.filters.tasks.statuses = angular.copy($scope.active_statusses);
    $scope.filters.tasks.statuses.push($scope.folder_status);
}
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

> track by $index

should do the trick, even with a nested structure, since $index will refer to the index on the innermost ngRepeat scope.

This will cause the items to be keyed by their position in the array instead of their value

Comment: Can you still filter with track by $index? https://coderwall.com/p/p-glog/angularjs-using-trackby-with-filters-in-an-ng-repeat

Comment: No, it's not possible - you can try it in the plunker. It will put there more nodes because of nested structure

Comment: Yes you can still filter using track by $index. But the one thing that you have to keep in mind is that you have to apply the filters before the track by expression. If you scroll down to the end of that page you will see an example